# Does the TfidfVectorizer implicitly threshold its fitted output for large datasets?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I'm trying to use `sklearn`'s `TfidfVectorizer` to output `tf-idf` scores for a list of inputs, comprised of both unigrams and bigrams.

Here's the essence of what I'm doing:

```
comprehensive_ngrams = comprehensive_unigrams + comprehensive_bigrams # List of unigrams and bigrams(comprehensive_unigrams and comprehensive_bigrams are lists in their own right)
print("Length of input list: ", len(comprehensive_ngrams))
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range = (1,2), lowercase = True)
vectorizer.fit(comprehensive_ngrams)
vocab = vectorizer.vocabulary_
print("Length of learned vocabulary: ", len(vocab))
term_document_matrix = vec.toarray()
print("Term document matrix shape is: ", term_document_matrix.shape)
```

This snippet outputs the following:

```
Length of input list: 12333

Length of learned vocabulary: 6196

Term document matrix shape is: (12333, 6196)
```

The length of the dictionary mapping input elements to positional indices emitted by the `TfidfVectorizer` is shorter than the number of unique inputs it's fed. This doesn't seem to be a problem for smaller datasets (on the order of ~50 elements) - the size of the dictionary the `TfidfVectorizer` produces once it has been fitted equals the size of the input.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that `comprehensive_ngrams` is a list of unique terms? Can there be non-unique entries? What is `len(set(comprehensive_ngrams))`?

Comment: @petezurich There are some non-unique entries in **comprehensive_ngrams*. I guess this is the culprit. However, I want the vectorizer to output all occurrences of a certain (redundant) term in the corpus with their corresponding individual tf-idf scores. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: That seems like a new question. Please post this as a seperate questions with a data sample and an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And if this answered your former question than please accept my answer so that others can see that the matter is solved.

Comment: Yes, I'll rephrase my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `comprehensive_ngrams` is a list of unique words. I.e.:

```
assert len(set(comprehensive_ngrams)) == len(comprehensive_ngrams)
```